# How to reverse the path direction of \psframe?

Tags: pstricks, programming

I think there is a bug in `\psframe` that behaves differently when we compare it with other closed curves in PSTricks.

The path direction of `\psframe` seems to be clockwise while that of other closed curves are counter-clockwise.

This phenomenon only occurs when `fillstyle=solid`. If I change to `fillstyle=eofill` then all the closed curves behave the same.

> [image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\pscustom
[
    %fillstyle=eofill,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=yellow
]
{
    \pscircle{6}
    \psframe(-3,2)(-1,4)
    \psccurve(1,2)(3,2)(3,4)(2,3)(1,4)
    \pspolygon(-5,-1)(-3,-1)(-4,1)
    \pswedge(-1,0){1}{45}{360}
    \psellipticwedge(3,0)(2,1){45}{360}
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \psellipse(2,-3)(2,1)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Question

How to reverse the path direction of  `\psframe`?

Note: Swapping the point in `\psframe(-3,2)(-1,4)`, i.e., `\psframe(-1,4)(-3,2)` does not help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\code{reversepath}`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]{%
        \pscircle{6}
        \code{reversepath}
        \psframe(-3,4)(-1,2)
        \psccurve(1,2)(3,2)(3,4)(2,3)(1,4)
        \pswedge(-1,0){1}{45}{360}
        \psellipticwedge(3,0)(2,1){45}{360}
        \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
        \psellipse(2,-3)(2,1)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then write your own `\psFrame`, for example

Comment: Create your own `pstricks.pro`. Search for the `/Rect ... def` function and change the order of the lines.

Comment: `\reversepath` in your code must be placed right after `\psframe`.

Comment: yes, but I thought you wanted _all_  vice versa filled.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Herbert's hint in his comment.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\pstVerb
{
    tx@Dict begin 
    /Rect { 
    x1 y2 moveto 
    x1 y1 lineto 
    x2 y1 lineto 
    x2 y2 lineto 
    x1 y2 lineto 
    closepath 
    } def end
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]{%
    \pscircle{6}
    \psframe(-3,4)(-1,2)
    \psccurve(1,2)(3,2)(3,4)(2,3)(1,4)
    \pswedge(-1,0){1}{45}{360}
    \psellipticwedge(3,0)(2,1){45}{360}
    \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
    \psellipse(2,-3)(2,1)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Or by using `\reversepath`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow]{%
        \pscircle{6}
        \psframe(-3,4)(-1,2)
        \reversepath
        \psccurve(1,2)(3,2)(3,4)(2,3)(1,4)
        \pswedge(-1,0){1}{45}{360}
        \psellipticwedge(3,0)(2,1){45}{360}
        \pscircle(-2,-3){1}
        \psellipse(2,-3)(2,1)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Write it into the preamble with: `\pstVerb{tx@Dict begin 
 /Rect { 
  x1 y2 moveto 
  x1 y1 lineto    
  x2 y1 lineto
  x2 y2 lineto
  x1 y2 lineto 
  closepath 
 } def end}`

Comment: @Herbert: Could you add a new object named `\psRectangle` with counter clockwise path to `pstricks.pro`? In addition, `\psRectangle` seems to be a better name than `\psframe` because frame is not a term used in geometry. I really appreciate if you can add it. Thank you!

Comment: I must think about it. Maybe that changing the Direktion in /Rect make more sense

Comment: @Herbert: Thank you very much for considering this issue.